# SQL copy and increase value in same table

Tags: sql

I have a public holiday table, with the following columns:

```
PublicHolidayID,
PublicHolidayDate,
PublicHolidayName,
IsStatic,
```

So for example: `24 December 2014` is Christmas and it is static date.

What I am looking for is a way of taking all static holidays, add a year and insert them into the same table, sort of auto-update for next year, so the user don't have to add them manually.

Problem I have is first time it works, I get `24/12/2014-24/12/2015`. second time I call the procedure I get: `24/12/2014-24/12/2014-24/12/2015-24/12/2015-24/12/2016-24/12/2016`

Can image what goanna next time I call the procedure

Any help will be nice...

Comment: What DB engine do you use?

Comment: How you want that autoupdate script to run, if its run once a year for next year ; then just select everything on that particular year and run with one year added to it; 
Insert into table (columns) select (columns+add1year) from table where  yearofdate = something and isstatic = true
also isnt it possible to make the date unique

Comment: What have you already tried? Although a simple problem, sometimes it will help to provide existing code so users can shine a light on what you might have done wrong rather than blindly giving you a solution

Comment: Why you even want to run a job to populate for next year. if you populate the table for next 50 years how many rows that table will have? unless there is a business requirement to restrict having a pre-populated public holidays for more than current year.
You can get the max(YEAR) GroupBy Month+Day and keep adding year for all rows where IsStatic=1. You can do that in Loop, Window Function, Cursor, and many other ways.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you run your query once a year to create all the holiday for next year,
schedule a job to run the below once a year

```
INSERT INTO PublicHolidays (HolidayDate,Name,IsStatic)
SELECT Dateadd(year,1,HolidayDate),Name,IsStatic
FROM PublicHolidays 
WHERE IsStatic=1 
      AND  YEAR(holidaydate) = datepart(year,getdate())
```

If you want to pouplate the table for the next 100 years, do this:

```
DECLARE @i INT;
SELECT @i = 1;
SET NOCOUNT ON
WHILE @i <= 100
BEGIN
    INSERT INTO PublicHolidays (HolidayDate,Name,IsStatic)
    SELECT Dateadd(year,@i,HolidayDate),Name,IsStatic
    FROM PublicHolidays 
    WHERE IsStatic=1 
       AND  YEAR(holidaydate) = datepart(year,getdate())
    SELECT @i = @i + 1;
END;
SET NOCOUNT OFF
```

Answer (score 0):

SQL Server solution

```
insert into PublicHolidays (HolidayDate,Name,IsStatic)
select Dateadd(year,1,HolidayDate),Name,IsStatic
from PublicHolidays where IsStatic=1 and YEAR(holidaydate) = 2014
```

Comment: OP is looking for code that can be run w/o changing and that provides next year date. above query will work only for 2015 and then he has to change again that code next year.

Comment: YEAR(GETUTCDATE()) --Run it every 31st december

Comment: Thanks guy's, So simple...must have been overthinking the problem.